# Calling component multiple times: Range error

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have this Upload component.When I run this, it prints multiple lines and finally shows error as `Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`

```
class Upload extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isUpload: false
    };
    this.afterUpload = this.afterUpload.bind(this);
    this.beforeUpload = this.beforeUpload.bind(this);
  }

beforeUpload(props) {
  this.setState({isUpload: true});
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Before Upload</h2>
    </div>
  )

}

afterUpload(props) {
  this.setState({isUpload: false});
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>After upload</h1>
    </div>
  )

}

render() {
  const isUpload = this.state.isUpload;
  console.log("state..." + isUpload);
  if(isUpload)
    return this.afterUpload();
  return this.beforeUpload();
}
}
```

It seems it is calling `beforeUpload` and `afterUpload` multiple times.I am not able to find any error here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is wrong. You are calling `this.afterUpload();` inside `render()`. And `this.afterUpload()` calling `setState()` which in turn call `render()` method and that will cause another call to `this.afterUpload();` Hence a loop. Remember evrytime you call `setState()` method, your component is re-rendered.

check this:

1. component rendered. inside render() method, `this.beforeUpload()`get called.
2. inside beforeUpload, `this.setState({isUpload: true});`will again call render method and this time `this.afterUpload()` get called.
3. Inside `this.afterUpload()`, `this.setState({isUpload: false})`, will again call render(), and this time `this.beforeUpload()` will get called.
4. Above step repeated.. and hence a loop.

**Suggested approcah.**

```
componentWillMount(){
   this.beforeUpload()
} 


beforeUpload(props) {
  this.setState({isUpload: true},()=>{//Put return statement inside setState callback
     return (
    <div>
      <h2>Before Upload</h2>
    </div>
  )
 });


}
```

Comment: If I want to render afterUpload and beforeUpload based on conditions then how should I do?

Comment: You can call this.beforeUpload() inside componentDidMount() or componentWillMount method